# How do I include a framework in my xcode project if I want to send it as zip

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, frameworks

Sorry this is somewhat a silly question, but I could do with some help with this.

Basically my app uses various Google Frameworks (maps, places etc). But when I compress my project and send it it stops working. I've included all the frameworks in the root folder of my project, here's the errors i'm getting:

[image]

Now when I look in at the framework in the left panel of xcode, it appears like this:

[image]

The headers have gone!

Here's how it should look:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your framework's directory isn't referenced properly. Go to your target -> Build Setting -> Search Path -> Framework Search Path and fix it accordingly.

However I would recommend you use a package manager like cocoapods as it will allow others to download all the frameworks necessary separately, and also it will allow you to easily update the frameworks to its latest version.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you done this while adding the framework?(like the image added)